# Does the stock SMS app of android utilize wakelocks to receive messages even while in deep sleep?

Tags: android

I'm planning to create an app which will act as a listener for messages and filter out messages containing certain keywords. Right now I'm thinking of what will the implications be on the battery life of my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incoming SMS are received by registering custom broadcast with following intent filter.

```
<receiver android:name="com.sample.sms_receiver">   
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

sms_receiver will be called in any case whenever a SMS is received. However you can consider starting WakefulIntent Service in onReceive as phone can go to sleep when onReceive returns if it was in sleep state before.